# question on radiobuttons ( \ChoiceMenu[radio,...] ) of a fillable form made with package hyperref

Tags: hyperref, pdf, forms

I often use radiobuttons ( \ChoiceMenu[radio,...] ). But there is one aspect I am not happy about: If you select/check a certain button of your group of radiobuttons, then without javascript there is no way to have all radiobuttons of the group again deselected/unchecked.

A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
{Do you want to: }%
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Do it all again=Again}
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Pretend it never happened=Pretend}
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Write a book about it=Write}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

I would like to get such a behavior of a group of radiobuttons as in section "Filling Status" in the upper part of this governmental [fillable pdf form](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf). If a selected/checked radiobutton once more is checked/selected, then the selection completely vanishes.

Is ist possible to produce such a group of radiobuttons with LaTex and hyperref without javascript? The above linked pdf is made with the software "Adobe LifeCycle Designer".

---

### Edit: (Peter Grill)

Initially the above produces:

[image]

Upon clicking on the first check box, we get:

[image]

The goal is to be able to check the first box in this state and revert back to the initial state (first image).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. I changed my post. It now contains an MWE.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also elaborate on what you mean by "If a selected/checked radiobutton once more is checked/selected, then the selection completely vanishes". I downloaded the form and using Acrobat 10.1.3 on a Mac I did not see the radio buttons vanishing.

Comment: I do not want the radiobutton to vanish. I want its selection to vanish. If a radiobutton is pressed, I would want to undo it without having to press an other buttton of the radio button group.

Comment: If you do a doubleclick at the radio button field "single" in the section "Filling Status" of the linked pdf, zero radio buttons will be pressed. Thats the aimed behavior I would like to reach using LaTex, hyperref and Form.

Comment: I have edited it in an attempt to make the requirements clearer. Please review and make an edits if needed.

Answer (score 7):

There's a flag called `NoToggleToOff` which should control this behavior according to the [PDF specification, p. 439](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=447):

> *(Radio buttons only)* If set, exactly one radio button shall be selected at all times; selecting the currently selected button has no effect. If clear, clicking the selected button deselects it, leaving no button selected.

However, this does not work as expected: even if the flag is not set, I wasn't able to deselect a once selected radio button. I tried with different viewers (Adobe Reader X, PDF-XChange Viewer, Foxit Reader [Windows]) and with PDF documents produced by different programs (LaTeX using `hyperref`, OpenOffice, [iText](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg56458.html)), with no success. Apparently, this feature of the specification [isn't implemented in any of the current PDF viewers](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=109913#c0)!

### So how were the radio buttons in the [linked form](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf) created?

The answer is quite surprising: The "radio buttons" in this PDF don't have the `Radio` flag set, which technically turns them into simple check boxes. However, as you can see, they still behave like radio buttons, so you can only select one option at a time. You can exploit this oddity by removing this flag in the form fields created by `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

% Make radio buttons completely deselectable by removing the "Radio" flag
% (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74543/3323)
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\HyField@FlagsRadioButton}{\HyField@SetFlag{Ff}{Radio}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\def\DefaultOptionsofRadio{print}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
{Do you want to: }%
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Do it all again=Again}
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Pretend it never happened=Pretend}
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Write a book about it=Write}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Like this, you get completely deselectable radio buttons like the ones in the form you provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
{Do you want to: }%
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Do it all again=Again,%
Pretend it never happened=Pretend,Write a book about it=Write}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Could you also add a few words on how your answer works?

Comment: I don't think this meets the requirements of the OP: Once a button is selected, re-selecting it again should revert to an unselected state.  See the updates in the question.