# Fillable forms with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, forms

I am trying to create a form with a preselected choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}    
  \ChoiceMenu[default=y,radio,name=test1]{Question:}{yes=y,no=n}\\
  \ChoiceMenu[default=n,radio,name=test2]{Question:}{yes=y,no=n}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

The pdf is generated with pdflatex

Unfortunately, the default parameter does not work for the second form.

[image]

Btw. The PDF is wrong in evince/gimp. Maybe this is related. Here, the result is:

[image]

```
$ pdflatex -version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.49
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.3
```

How can I fix this?

**update [2014-01-14]**

If I uncompress the resulting PDF with

```
pdftk test.pdf output test2.pdf uncompress
```

and replace in test2.pdf the first occurence of

```
/V /Off
/T (test2)
```

by

```
/V /n
/T (test2)
```

then it works. It seems that the generated PDF is wrong.

Comment: I suspect the weird display is some kind of interaction with poppler because I get the same with Okular. I've seen this before and I can't remember whether I found an answer or, if so, what it was...

Comment: For some reason, I think poppler-based pdf viewers are trying to print the *commas* which separate the buttons in the display. No idea why, obviously. I don't think this will help directly, but it does suggest there are at least some bugs in the vicinity: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58447/question-on-radiobuttons-choicemenuradio-of-a-fillable-form-made-with?rq=1.

Comment: This all refers to the wrong display problem with poppler-based viewers. For Abobe Reader everything works except the default selection (second line of first example). Could this be a problem of hyperref?

Comment: This might be related but is only in German: http://de.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/t4iwEKxi/hyperref-combobox-und-defaultwerte

Comment: I provided a workaround for this hyperref problem: https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?202

Comment: This seems to work with a recent version of `hyperref`: tested with TeX Live 2017 and `hyperref` v6.85a, i get [the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBYcc.png).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the error cannot be reproduced with a current TeX installation.

Comment: I still get the result of the second picture when generating the pdf. I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Document Viewer 3.36.10.