# Problem with the select/deselect of radio buttons once all the options are selected one-by-one

Tags: hyperref, pdf, forms

I am using **radiobuttons ( \ChoiceMenu[radio,...] )** and make them completely deselectable by removing the "Radio" flag using instructions from the following link:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74543/3323

But here comes and other issue.

**If I select and deselect all the options (A,B,C,D) one-by-one and then select option A again, it selects/deselects all the options at once.**

Sample code is shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\HyField@FlagsRadioButton}{\HyField@SetFlag{Ff}{Radio}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\def\DefaultOptionsofRadio{print}

\begin{document}

Select the Einstein's mass energy equivalence.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
    \item \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{\texorpdfstring{$F = ma$}{}}
    \item \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{\texorpdfstring{$F = \dfrac{dp}{dt}$}{}}
    \item \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{\texorpdfstring{$E = hf$}{}}
    \item \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{\texorpdfstring{$E = mc^2$}{}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Is there any solution to this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is missing the initialization with \begin{Form} or \Form.

Beside this: you are using a `\texorpdfstring` with empty second argument, that means that all fields have the same value in the pdf. If you add there something unique it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\HyField@FlagsRadioButton}{\HyField@SetFlag{Ff}{Radio}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\def\DefaultOptionsofRadio{print}

\begin{document}
\Form % initialization
Select the Einstein's mass energy equivalence.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
    \item \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{\texorpdfstring{$F = ma$}{a}}
    \item \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{\texorpdfstring{$F = \dfrac{dp}{dt}$}{b}}
    \item \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{\texorpdfstring{$E = hf$}{c}}
    \item \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{\texorpdfstring{$E = mc^2$}{d}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But this is clearly against the pdf reference, radio buttons should have the flag set, so you are relying on some undocumented side effect.